# How to detect screen mirroring enabled on android device

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Is it possible to  detect that screen mirroring to chromcast device is enabled?
especially from my Android app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChromeCast Mirroring is handled with the exact same code as a MHL secondary display.  Look at DisplayManager and Presentation APIs (api v17+).  DisplayManager also has subclasses for listening to displaychanges.